# How to remove Integer from String using delimiter

Tags: java

I am using Java Scanner class to delimit a String

Here is my string

```
locations:[{linkId:21737516,latLng:{lat:12.9219,lng:77.56022},type:s},

{linkId:21741609,latLng:{lat:12.921509,lng:77.49382},type:s},

{linkId:18632091,latLng:{lat:12.904157,lng:77.470489},type:v},

{linkId:76684742,latLng:{lat:12.88959,lng:77.45314},type:s}
```

I am using

```
s.useDelimiter("linkId");
```

I remove linkid but how can remove `linkId:Integer` from the above set of `String`
which has diffrent integer??

please help me

Comment: you mean you need integer part of linkid?

Comment: Please show us sample input and expected output..

Comment: Perhaps you describe what really needs to be done: skip linkId:18632091,`but then continue to read using a Scanner? You don't "delimit" a string using a scanner, you parse =(= extract its substrings).

Comment: Hey here is my i/p                                           locations:[{:21737516,latLng:{lat:12.9219,lng:77.56022},type:s},

{:21741609,latLng:{lat:12.921509,lng:77.49382},type:s}, From this I want to remove  :21737516, & :21741609,  along with comma  How should I do that please help

Answer (score 2):

Try using a simple regex:

```
s.useDelimiter("linkId:\\d+");
```

`\\d+` will include the digits after the `:`

Comment: i voted u up but why not using replace it with "" or something like that?